# marginal pdf of exponential functions

Tags: probability-theory, random-variables

Hi I have a question about marginal PDFs of exponentials. Given is :

$$f(x,y)=y \text{ for } y\leqslant \ e^{-x/4} \text{ and } 0 \text{ otherwise}.$$

I have sketched the graph and got an exponential curve. Question is what parameters is the marginal PDF of $X$ and $Y$ supposed to take? My assumptions:

$$f_X(x)= \int_0^{e^{-x/4}}y \ dy$$

and $f_Y(y)= \int_0^{e^{-x/4}}y \ dx$ which doesn't make sense to me for $f(y)$ (according to the solutions given) why is the parameter in terms of $x$ and not $y$?

moreover, what would be the parameters given to the expected values?

for $\operatorname{E}(X)=\int_0^\infty x \ f(x) \ dx$ because of the asymptote.

what would it be for $\operatorname{E}(Y)= \int_0^\text{?} y \ f(y) \, dy$?

Apart from that, how would the independence be determined from the graph? I know the equation for indepedence is $f(x,y) = f(x)f(y)$ but is the correct way  of using it by plugging in x=0 and y=0 and see if they are equal to each other?

Comment: Was there a constraing on $x,$ such as $f(x,y)=0$ when $x<0$?

Comment: the question was given so as I have written it, so I guess not

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks as if your pdf must be
$$
f(x,y) = \begin{cases} y & \text{if } x\ge0 \text{ and } 0\le y\le e^{-x/4}, \\[5pt] 0 & \text{if } x<0 \text{ or } y<0 \text{ or } y>e^{-x/4}. \end{cases}
$$
The marginal pdf for $Y$ is
$$
f_Y(y) = \int_0^\infty f_{X,Y} (x,y) \, dx.
$$
You "integrate out" $x,$ getting a function of $y.$ This is similar to a situation with a function of two discrete variables, $i$ and $j,$ both taking values in the set $\{1,2,3\}:$
$$
p_I(i) = \sum_{j=1}^3 p_{I,J}(i,j) = \overbrace{p(1,j)+p(2,j)+p(3,j)}
$$
The part under the $\overbrace{\text{overbrace}}$ is a function only  of $j$ and not of $i;$ the variable $i$ has been "summed out."

The density is $0$ when $y> e^{-x/4},$ and that is the same as $\log y > -x/4,$ or $-4\log y > x.$ And not that $\log y$ is negative since $y<1,$ so $-4\log y$ is positive.

You have
\begin{align}
f_Y(y) & = \int_0^\infty f_{X,Y}(x,y)\, dx = \int_0^\infty \left. \begin{cases} y & \text{if } x< -4\log y \\ 0 & \text{if } x>-4\log y \end{cases}  \right\} \, dx \\[10pt]
& = \int_0^{-4\log y} y \, dx = -4y\log y \quad \text{provided } 0<y<1.
\end{align}
This density is $0$ at the two endpoints $0$ and $1,$ and is not symmetric.

As for "parameters," you can't talk about those unless you choose some parametrized family of distributions that contains this one.

You also have
$$
f_X(x) = \int_0^1 f_{X,Y}(x,y)\,dy = \int_0^{e^{-x/4}} y \, dy = \frac{e^{-x/2}} 2 \quad \text{provided } x>0.
$$
This is an exponential distribution with expected value $2.$

Comment: Thanks I understood all of it except the last part where you calculate the expected value. For $E(X)$ it is clear, but for $E(Y)$ (according to my answer sheet) why is the upper bound infinity and lower bound 0? shouldnt the upperbound be $e^{-x/4}$ ?

Comment: sorry to ask again but if i were to calculate $E(XY)$ what should be the lower and upper bound for both integrals  $x$ and $y$ be? It doesn't seem to work if I use for $dy$ $\int_0^1$ and $dx$ $\int_0^\infty$

Comment: thanks again, but I am still confused about choosing the bounds for density functions and marginal pdfs. Why is that when we calculate $E(X)$ we can integrate from 0 to infinity but  when we calculate $E(XY)$ we use $\int_0^{e^{-x/4}}$ for $dx$ does it have anything to do with the fact that $E(XY)$ a 2D random variable is and has to be calculated differently?

Comment: @Kev : There is an error above; stand by.......

Comment: CORRECTED VERSION: $$ \begin{align} \operatorname{E}(XY) & = \iint\limits_{ \Large \{(x,y) \, : \, 0\,\le\,x\ \&\ 0\,\le\,y\,\le\,e^{-x/4} \} } xy f_{X,Y}(x,y) \, d(x,y) \\ \\ & = \int_0^\infty \left( \int_0^{\large e^{-x/4}} xy f_{X,Y}(x,y) \, dy \right) \, dx \\  \\ & =  \int_0^1 \left( \int_0^{\large -e\log y} xy f_{X,Y}(x,y)  \, dx\right) \, dy. \end{align} $$ ERRATUM: In an earlier, now deleted, comment, I had $dx$ and $dy$ interchanged. It doesn't make sense of the bounds of integration to depend on $x$ when you have $\displaystyle \int\cdots\cdots \, dx. \qquad$

Comment: . . . . nor for the bounds to depend on $y$ in $\displaystyle \int \cdots\cdots\,dy. \qquad$

Comment: hi If I am not wrong I see that you did a change on the order of integrals. I have been scouring the internet for the way to do it but can't seem to find anything that would help me picture this particular case. How do I go about it if i may ask?

Comment: @Kev : I was saying that you could do it in either of those two orders. But in both cases, it's just a matter of making sure you're integrating over the set identified in the double integral displayed at the top, i.e. $0\,\le\,x\ \&\ 0\,\le\,y\,\le\,e^{-x/4}. $ Thus you have $\displaystyle \int_0^\infty \cdots \cdots \, dx$ and another integral inside that: $\displaystyle \int_0^\infty \left( \int \cdots\cdots\, dy \right) dx.$ In the inside integral the value of $x$ is fixed and so you ask which values of $y$ are in the region for that fixed value of $x,$ and you have $0\le y\le e^{-x/4}.$